# Questions Related to Umbrella companies

Tags: taxes

I live in Greece and as you know in Greece the finacial situation is bad. So it make me reluctant to job offers for a freelance-contract job that I receive via mail and some of them pay well. I am thinking of working as freelancer but I have not registered as one yet and of cource I have not done any freelance job yet because of heavy tax cost.

Therefore I was thinking use an umbrella company that will cast all these worries away. But I want to ask some questions before I take a decision:

1. What are the pos and cons of using an umbrella company?
2. Does the sites such as upwork, peopleperhour, freelancer.com work as umbrella companies?

Usually the job offers are in European Union countries such as Belgium.

## Edit 1

As requested Umbrella company I mean this term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_company

Comment: I think you may need to explain what *you* mean by "umbrella company".

Answer (score 0):

In Umbrella term we usually user term Agency or middle man.

Working for an agency pros:

- you get work without having to look for clients
- you will get all kinds of work and can grow in your knowledge

Cons:

- you are usually underpaid. what they offer is a rate for a senior probably and you will be offered junior rate
- they deliver work and want it be done, without caring about holidays, weekends, vacations, etc.
- often you are paid when they are so you both share the risk. fight that you are paid for their work and they handle the risk only

In general, I have always avoided agencies, unless I know the guy who runs it. I would rather take work from another guy from the same niche who does not have time to finish it. you will earn more.

I suggest you try to work as a direct freelancer via freelancing websites. And when and if you start earning, you can then register a company. But I think Greece has the same law like my country: you do not have to pay taxes or register business until you start earning serious money. It means for small money (you can expect small money as a beginner), you will not have to pay taxes or register company. But please, check you local laws, don't believe my words in full.